# How to test an EMI Filter & Power Mains Lead using a multimeter

Tags: mac, power-supply, imac

I'm currently trying to repair an iMac A1311 (Mid 2011). None of the diagnostic LEDs come on so I believe the problem is a power issue.

Tech aside, how can I test that an EMI Filter & Power Mains Lead is functioning?

Specifically, this EMI filter: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-iMac-21-5-604-2027-Model-A1311-Mid-2011-EMI-Filter-Power-Mains-Lead-/231737610147

There is a 2 pin connector on the end that I believe I need to use my multimeter on.

Here is my multimeter: [https://www.amazon.com/Etekcity-Multimeter-MSR-R500-Electronic-Multimeters/dp/B01N9QW620/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1537844438&sr=8-2&keywords=etekcity+multimeter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N9QW620)

I am extremely new to this time of thing, if you can't already tell.

So my questions are:

- What setting do I set my multimeter to? V with the line on top and 3
  lines below? A with the line on top and 3 lines below, etc?
- Where do I put the positive and negative lines to test? One line on
  one of the 2 pins and one on the other?
- What should I expect for output? I've been reading 12 volts but I'm
  not sure.

If anybody could help me that would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: What you expect for output depends on what you have for input – and I don't quite understand what you're trying to test. Is the mains lead connected to something and you want to test if it's energized _(if I have the correct term)_? Is it completely disconnected and you want to test if electricity _can_ pass from one end to another? Something else?

Comment: (And just to mention, anything involving power supplies is _not_ something you want to learn by experimentation, at least not without someone more qualified overseeing you.)

Comment: I want to know if the EMI filter is functional by connecting my power cable to it and testing how many volts it outputs with a multimeter.